# Query for parent entity using two fields from child entity using CriteriaQuery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

Having the below entities

```
class Parent {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;
    @OneToMany 
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_fk")
    List<Child> children; 
}

class Child {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String sex; //male, female
    String name;
}
```

How would you construct the following query using CriteriaBuilder?

```
SELECT * FROM Parent p JOIN Child c ON p.id = c.parent_fk WHERE c.sex='male' AND (c.name = 'Tom' OR c.name='Jim')
```

Thank you

update:
So my mistake was that instead of doing

```
Join<Parent, Child> c = p.join("children");
Predicate predicate = builder.or(
     builder.equal( c.get("name"), name1 ),
     builder.equal( c.get("name"), name2 )
);
```

I was doing:

```
Predicate predicate = builder.or(
     builder.equal( p.join("children").get("name"), name1 ),
     builder.equal( p.join("children").get("name"), name2 )
);
```

Which was causing 2 inner joins with the child table, one for each p.join i was using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Parent> criteria = builder.createQuery(Parent.class);

Root<Parent> p = criteria.from(Parent.class);
Join<Parent, Child> c = p.join("children");

criteria.select(p);

ParameterExpression<String> name1 = builder.parameter( String.class );
ParameterExpression<String> name2 = builder.parameter( String.class );
ParameterExpression<String> sex = builder.parameter( String.class );

Predicate predicate = builder.or(
  builder.equal( c.get("name"), name1 ),
  builder.equal( c.get("name"), name2 )
);

predicate = builder.and(
  builder.equal( c.get("sex"), sex ),
  predicate
);

criteria.where(predicate);

List<Parent> result = entityManager.createQuery( criteria )
  .setParameter( name1, "Tom" )
  .setParameter( name2, "Jim" )
  .setParameter( sex, "male" )
  .getResultList();
```